# Angular Directive isolated scope not updating

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have created this angular directive which works up to a point.

```
app.directive('albumArt', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
        'pictures': '=pictures',
        'source' : '@source'
    },
    replace: true,
    template: '<img ng-src="{{source}}" width="30" height="30">',

    link: function( scope, element, attrs ){
         angular.forEach( scope.pictures, function( value, key ){
         //console.log( value.album, attrs.album );
         if( value.album == attrs.album ){
          scope.source="data:" + value.mime_type + ";base64," + value.picture;
          //console.log( value.mime_type );
         }
        }); 
      }
    };
});
```

It's being called via:

```
<album-art pictures='pictures' album='{{album.title}}' source='{{default}}' class="pull-left art"></album-art>
```

pictures is an array, album title is obvious and source is set in the main app controller to a default image.

The problem I'm having is when a match is found in the forEach loop within the directive link: function, scope.source is set but not updating the template {{source}} reference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It looks like it should work, what's actually showing up the html when it's run?

Comment: I think you need to call `scope.$apply` when changing the local scope from within a link function.

Comment: Also, I'm completely puzzled by your forEach. Are you trying to create multiple `<img>` tags? Because right now all it seems to be doing is assigning the source value of the last matching picture in an album to `scope.source`.

Comment: @NewDev Exactly right, if an image is in the pictures array then set ng-src to this, if not set a default image.

Comment: I have fixed this but can't post answer to my own question. I will edit the OP.

Comment: You should post answer to your own question - that's encouraged.

Comment: But, it loops goes over the entire array, and eventually would assign only the last matching value. If that's the intent, why not loop starting from the end and `break` the loop on first match

Comment: @NewDev Because angularjs does not support breaks in forEach loops as far as I'm aware after extensive research. If it did I would.

Comment: It doesn't... I meant, the old fashioned for-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solved this by removing the isolated scope and allowing the directive to inherit from parent scope.

Initiated simply by:

```
<album-art album='{{album}}'></album-art>
```

or

```
<album-art album='{{album.title}}'></album-art>
```

depending on app view. The directive now looks like this:

```
app.directive('albumArt', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    template: '<img ng-src="{{source}}" width="30" height="30">',

    link: function( scope, element, attrs ){
        for( i = 0; i <= scope.pictures.length; i++ ){
            if( scope.pictures[i].album == attrs.album ){
                scope.source="data:" + scope.pictures[i].mime_type + ";base64," + scope.pictures[i].picture;
                break;
            }
        };
     }
  };
});
```

I get a single img either default.png or the album artwork if it exists.

Thanks for all your comments and suggestions.